How to get pdfrenderer instance via uri in jetpack compose
Basically I'd like to get the pagecount of the pdf whose uri that i'm inputting in the function but it seems to keep failing and I am struggling to figure out why.
I've been trying to wrap my hand around how to get it working reliably but the app just keeps crashing. My last attempt is commented below.
fun getPdfPageCount(context: Context, uri: Uri): Int {
//    val contentResolver = context.contentResolver
    val uri_string:String = uri.toString()
    var pageCount = 0
    Toast.makeText(
        context,
        "pageCount = $uri" ,
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
    ).show()

// Open a file descriptor for the PDF
    var renderer: PdfRenderer? = null

//Problem area:

//    val pdfFile = File(uri_string)
//
//    ParcelFileDescriptor.open(pdfFile, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY).use { parcelFileDescriptor ->
//        val pdfRenderer = PdfRenderer(parcelFileDescriptor)
//        pageCount = pdfRenderer.pageCount
//        pdfRenderer.close()
//    }

    return pageCount
}

I'd really love any insight anyone can give me.

Please [edit] your question and add a [mre] that we can execute to reproduce the crash. Also please add the stacktrace and point out the code line that causes the crash.
